# Is there a way to eliminate repeating the same filter by using a function in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Pandas, but trying something I've never seen in the wild. I am trying to eliminate repeated lines in Python (using Pandas) code.
I'd like use the data that I'm filtering/slicing into a variable and just use the variable.
Ideally, I use a function to call this where I pass in the filter. Right now the code below is very difficult to read and maintain, but it follows a pattern where I might be slicing a dataframe , adding values to a field based on that slice, and exporting the results to a csv.

```
        df.loc[(df[field1].str.contains('Galvanized|Lead',flags=re.IGNORECASE) == True) & ((df[field2] == 'TP-returnForFull') & (df[field3] == 'NO')), reportErrorCodeField] = errCode
        df.loc[(df[field1].str.contains('Galvanized|Lead',flags=re.IGNORECASE) == True) & ((df[field2] == 'TP-returnForFull') & (df[field3] == 'NO')), reportErrorCodeDescField] = errDesc 
        if len(df[(df[field1].str.contains('Galvanized|Lead',flags=re.IGNORECASE) == True) & ((df[field2] == 'TP-returnForFull') & (df[field3] == 'NO'))]) == 0:
            writeEmptyCSVrecordMessage(csvPath + '\\' + csvFileName, "ALL", errCode, "No records")
        else:
            df[reportFlds][(df[field1].str.contains('Galvanized|Lead',flags=re.IGNORECASE) == True) & ((df[field2] == 'TP-returnForFull') & (df[field3] == 'NO'))].to_csv(csvPath + '\\' + csvFileName, mode='a', header=False)
```

Ideally I'd like to pass in the contents of (df[field1].str.contains('Galvanized|Lead',flags=re.IGNORECASE) == True) & ((df[field2] == 'TP-returnForFull') & (df[field3] == 'NO')) into a variable, so I'm not repeating the same code over and over again which makes it tedious to maintain.

My end goal is to get something similar to below:

```
dataFilter = (df[field1].str.contains('Galvanized|Lead',flags=re.IGNORECASE) == True) & ((df[field2] == 'TP-returnForFull') & (df[field3] == 'NO'))
df.loc[dataFilter, reportErrorCodeField] = errCode
df.loc[dataFilter, reportErrorCodeDescField] = errDesc 
if len(df[dataFilter]) == 0:
    writeEmptyCSVrecordMessage(csvPath + '\\' + csvFileName, "ALL", errCode, "No records")
else:
    df[reportFlds][dataFilter].to_csv(csvPath + '\\' + csvFileName, mode='a', header=False)
```

Comment: What is wrong with your "goal" code at the bottom of your post?

Comment: Syntactically it doesn't work.

Comment: I guess I could try something like dataFilter = df.loc[(df[field1].str.contains('Galvanized|Lead',flags=re.IGNORECASE) == True) & ((df[field2] == 'TP-returnForFull') & (df[field3] == 'NO'))]

Comment: I think you need `df.loc[data_filter][reportErrorCodeField]`.  In my experience, `loc` and `iloc` don't always play nice with selecting columns.